leaflet markercluster spiderfy not working
update: added the minimum code to reproduce the problem

per the markercluster docs

spiderfy: Spiderfies the child markers of this cluster

I take it to understand that if I have code like so, clicking on a marker will cause the containing marker cluster to spiderfy (if it is indeed a markercluster, and not a stand alone marker).
update: added more detailed code below.
However, I get the error that foo.spiderfy() is not a function. How can I achieve what I want?
To summarize, if I click on a cluster, it spiderfies. Then, if I click on an individual marker in that cluster and fire the click event, I want the cluster to remain spiderfied and not collapse into a cluster.
minimum code to reproduce the problem
var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 11);
L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    maxZoom: 19,
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
}).addTo(map);

const points = [
    [51.509, -0.08],
    [51.503, -0.06],
    [51.51, -0.047]
];

const foo = L.markerClusterGroup();

for (const point of points) { 
    const marker = L.marker(point);
    marker.on('click', function(e) {

        // recenter map to the clicked point. Note that this is
        // the key action that causes the map to recenter, and
        // zoom to a level where, normally, this marker collapses
        // back into a cluster. And, this is the behavior that I
        // want to prevent
        map.flyTo(point, 11);

        // Now, spiderfy the cluster, if it is still a cluster
        // at this new center and zoom combo

        // We find the right cluster
        const cluster = foo.getVisibleParent(marker);
        
        if (cluster) {
            console.log('the clicked marker is indeed a part of a cluster');

            // Spiderfy only if marker is in cluster
            foo.spiderfy(cluster);
        }
    });
    foo.addLayer(marker);
}

map.addLayer(foo);

note1: I am using markerCluster 1.4.1
note2: the console indeed tells me that the clicked marker is indeed a part of a cluster

check the usage section of the docs: http://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.markercluster/#usage

I did check the usage section. I am not sure what you are referring to that might answer my question

Take a look at this code, it should work.
const points = [
  [51.509, -0.08],
  [51.503, -0.06],
  [51.51, -0.047],
];

const foo = L.markerClusterGroup();

for (const point of points) {
  const marker = L.marker(point);

  marker.on("click", function () {
    map.flyTo(point, 11);

    const cluster = foo.getVisibleParent(marker);

    if (cluster) {
      console.log("Marker jest częścią klastra");

      map.setView(cluster.getLatLng(), map.getZoom());
    }
  });

  foo.addLayer(marker);
}

map.addLayer(foo);


nope, does not work. I get the same message that foo.spiderfy() is not a function

Added minimum code that reproduces the problem to the original post

Ok, I changed the code, it should work properly now.

thanks, but where is the spiderfy() function in your code? It is missing. As I summarized in my original post -- "if I click on a cluster, it spiderfies. Then, if I click on an individual marker in that cluster and fire the click event that changes the icon of the marker to indicate it was clicked, causes an info panel to open up, and recenters the map to the clicked marker. However, when the map recenters, the marker collapses back into the cluster and is no longer visible. I want the cluster to remain spiderfied so that the clicked marker remains visible."

further explanation -- let's say I am at zoom 7 and looking at a cluster. I click on the cluster, it expands, showing individual markers. I click on a marker. All I wrote above happens, the map recenters, still is at zoom 7, so the  markers collapse back into a cluster. That is the crux of the problem. I am hoping that forcing that cluster to spiderfy() will keep my clicked marker visible.

I have pushed my project online so the problem can be viewed first-hand. Go to https://ocellus.info/maps.html and zoom in a level so the clusters come into view. Click on a cluster so it spiderfies. Click on one of its markers. An info window will open and the map will recenter. But, the clicked marker will collapse back into the cluster so it won't be visible by itself anymore. That is the problem
